# How to deep link to location sharing page in google maps application

Tags: android, google-maps, deep-linking, google-maps-urls

From my Android application, I need to open the location sharing page of Google Maps. I can launch the google maps application using following code snippet,

```
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

or

```
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:latitude,longitude?z=zoom"));
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

What should I do to launch the "Location Sharing" page(refer the image below) Google maps?

[image]

Comment: Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:latitude,longitude?z=zoom"));
startActivity(mapIntent);
this is better because here your sharing your exact information with details

Comment: That's ok. But I need a solution to launch the location sharing page

Answer (score -1):

Check below code. This is from google's guideline.

```
    Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=Taronga+Zoo,+Sydney+Australia");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Check below link for more help : 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents

Comment: Thanks for the response. But this only launches the Google maps app not the location sharing page.

Comment: Try with google.navigation. There are so many alternatives available as per your requirement.

Comment: you can pass your lat long in query

Comment: Please refer the image attached with the question

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents#launch_turn-by-turn_navigation  Check this link. you will get exactly what you want.

Comment: No solution for my question in that page

Comment: That will open location sharing screen. But obviously that is not as same as display on screen shot.